# Django admin Содержимое списка, зависящее от выбора из другого

Tags: django, django-admin

Как в Django админке сделать такое
Есть модель со списком производителей автомобилей
Есть модель со списком марок машин, с внешним ключом к производителю
И как сделать 3юю модель в которой при выборе производителя, будет показан только список марок этого производителя?
Думал, это базовая задача, но решения подробного не нашел
Увидел такое видео, но из-за малого опыта немного ясно
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KAySsGQF1oc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68936683/how-can-i-link-connect-two-dropdowns-in-django-admin

Comment: Встроенного красивого решения точно нет. Надо или самом писать на ajax, или искать какую-то библиотеку.